# Get Informix/NHibernate Session ID from IIS connection pooling

Tags: nhibernate, iis-7, connection-pooling, informix, sessionid

I am trying to the SID (Session ID) for a currently used connection, so I can audit what users are using what connections.

The use for this is that long running queries can be killed individually by our DBA and the users alerted that their process has been killed (or something to that extent...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you what the NHibernate Session ID might be and how it might be found.

You can obtain the session ID on the Informix server by using the built-in function `DBINFO('sessionid')`, for example as:

```
SELECT DBINFO('sessionid') FROM informix.systables WHERE tabid = 1;
```

Note that the argument to DBINFO must be a literal string.  When I ran it, it produced the answer '30', which corresponded to the `sessid` column in the output of `onstat -u` for the Informix data server.

Comment: Thanks for that - We've changed out idea to work around that this can't be done... We're going to use some sort of impersonisation instead!